# What is the right way to not use reserved public name withing web-component

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

When I run a build with stencil, I get

```
[Warn]
The @Prop() name "title" is a reserved public name. Please rename the "title"
 prop so it does not conflict with an existing standardized prototype member.
 Reusing prop names that are already defined on the element's prototype may
 cause unexpected runtime errors or user-interface issues on various browsers,
 so it's best to avoid them entirely.
```

I know it's only a warning but since it may cause unexpected runtime errors, I was wondering if some standard for naming it already existed. (since `title` was for me the more obvious propriety name to use).
If not, what would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, the only workaround I found was to add `attributes` as property and pass all the information through this variable, like the following

```
attributes: {
  title: string
  description: string
  /** ... */
}
```

I didn't found better than that.
But I'm still open to any ideas

Answer (score 0):

`title` is a global html attribute name - 'reserved'. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes. As a best practice, you shouldn't use global attribute names for @Props. I don't know of any 'standard' for naming a property which is the title of your component but isn't the same as the global title attribute (which is usually used for the tooltip).

Comment: I know that it's a reserved attribute name. It's the why I asked. But since Ionic use the name **header** for there [alert component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert) i think I gonna do the same.

Comment: Semantically "header" and "title" are not really the same (a "header" is a section or area). "Heading" would be a better choice IMO or perhaps "description" (depends on the nature of the component). In your alert example, another option would be "alertTitle". There are many "standard" ways to name things. Naming conventions are normally defined for software projects just like code standards. There isn't one single way that it "must" be done. The main "rule" is to be consistent throughout your code in the way you name things like props, methods, etc. - especially if they are part of public API.

Comment: "alertTitle" seems for me to be a bad idea, since more and more web component are going to be use, a single name for every components title would be much easier to remember. I'm consistent throughout my code but was only wondering how does the people out here doing since I wasn't able to find a standard anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Properties and component attributes are strongly connected but not necessarily the same thing.
We cannot use the title variable because of the HTMLElement prop type, but we can set the field text as title like this

```
@Prop({ attribute: 'title' }) heading?: string;
```

Comment: You're still using the attribute `title`, which shall not be used. 

So I do not understand how you're solution is helping. 

The question was more, does you guys have a standard, how are people naming such variable.

Thx for the try anyway

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet who said that the attribute name would not be used? an attribute is not a variable or definition from any prototype, it's just a string. Correct me if I'm wrong we're all here to learn something :)

Comment: The problem here in that question was the following. I **can** use the `title` attributes, bout I **shouln't** do it, because this name is reserved by the [web](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp). So my question was, which name should we use instead? and wanted to know if anybody had a standard for this one.